# Why does 'Web browser control's URL shows javascript:false;' lack enough info to diagnose?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

The question [Web browser control's URL shows javascript:false;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474360/web-browser-controls-url-shows-javascriptfalse) started off by lacking enough info to diagnose, but after the edit of the OP it became answerable for me.

Did the close voters that visited the question robo-close it, or does it indeed lack enough info?

I would like to vote to reopen it, but before I do that I like to hear if I'm too mellow.

<sub>I'm biased, I answered the question...</sub>

Comment: ..and it's open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After cleaning up the spelling and grammar of the post, I've voted to reopen it. With the updated code snippet it was obvious enough for you to answer it, so I'm fine with it being reopened.